# Error: 400 (MALA PETICIÓN) con oauth2 y angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, oauth2

Buenas, soy nuevo con angular 2 y estoy haciendo la parte de inicio de sesión de una aplicación web y al hacer el llamado http post con el usuario y contraseña me devuelve el error:

> 400 (MALA petición).

Lo codifique según lo vi en internet y no puedo encontrar el error. Ademas lo pruebo en `POSTMAN` y funciona correctamente.

El llamado es el siguiente:

```
    login(username, password){
      let client_id = "xxxxxxxxxx";
      let client_secret = "xxxxxxxxx";
      let grant_type ="password";        

      return this._http.post(url, {
      username, password, grant_type,client_id, client_secret
      } ).map(res =>{
        res.json()
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema es la falta de cabecera y su clave-valor *Content-type*.

En este caso la petición es de tipo POST y se necesita enviar el objeto JSON como parte del *body* de la petición http. El header mínimo sería el siguiente (inicializado con código **Angular**).

```
 headers: Headers = new Headers();
 this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Este header puede ser inicializado de manera global si va a ser utilizado en un Service de Angular para varias peticiones, o antes de cada petición en caso de ser específicas. 
El método para tu login podría implementarse de la siguiente manera:

```
  login(username, password) {
     return this.http.post(url,
        {
          username, password, grant_type, client_id, client_secret
        }, 
        { headers: this.headers }
     ).map(res => { res.json() });
```

Ten en cuenta que puede que en alguna petición de este tipo la información vaya completamente contenida en variables clave valor del header, en cuyo caso deberías añadir a tu header algo similar a esto:

```
this.headers.append('username', 'XXXXXXXX');
this.headers.append('password', 'XXXXXXXX');
this.headers.append('grant_type', 'password');
this.headers.append('client_id', 'XXXXXXXX');
this.headers.append('client_secret', 'XXXXXXXX');
```

Te recomiendo que utilices las peticiones http con el siguiente formato para mejorar la limpieza y eficiencia del código (ejemplo de petición POST):

```
   /**
   * POST - publicar/enviar un objecto JSON
   * @param url 
   * @param object
   */
  post(url: string, object): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.post(url, 
        JSON.stringify(object), { headers: this.headers })
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  /* Util http methods */
  private extractData(res: Response): Observable<any> {
    return res.json() || { };
  }

  private handleError(error: any){
    return Observable.throw("Error: Petición errónea");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si en postman funciona ve que tipo de petición haces:

[image: POSTMAN REQUEST]

No incluyes muchos detalles de tu back, pero, debe hacer que tu back reciba peticiones del tipo que le haces desde el angular o en angular hacer la petición correcta que tu back recibe.

Para que tengas una mejor idea de que envías desde postman ve a "code" y observa como hace la petición:

[image: code in postman]

[image: Request type]

Una vez que sepas que tipo de petición estas haciendo en la documentación de angular puede buscar como hacer un POST o GET y establecer las opciones en las cabeceras para enviar un "Content_Type" correcto.

Saludos.